# Read updated message body in Outlook 2003

Tags: vb6, outlook-2003, outlook-redemption

I have an application that uses the Redemption library.  A user can open a meeting and add some notes to a cancellation.  Prior to them editing it, the message body is already set with some default text.  Is there a way to get the new updated message body after the message is open and before the message is sent? Using

```
safeItem.Body
```

where safeItem is a SafeAppointmentItem from Redemption doesn't seem to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

If I change the call to:

```
Set app = Outlook.Application
Set bodyText = app.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Body
```

it works but, I get a warning popup (which is unacceptable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to this.  Calling a

```
safeItem.save
```

will update the item.body.